# Exact match of variable string in SPARQL Wikidata Query Service

Tags: sparql, string-matching, wikidata-query-service

Exact match of variable string in SPARQL Wikidata Query Service at https://query.wikidata.org does not give the the results I expected.

I was expecting I could do:

```
SELECT * {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
  { SELECT DISTINCT (xsd:string(?author_name_) AS ?author_name) { wd:Q5565155 skos:altLabel ?author_name_ . } }
  ?work wdt:P2093 ?author_name .
}
```

But I get no returned results from the Wikidata Query Service:

However, if I use the "=" comparison, I can match the strings:

```
SELECT * {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
  { SELECT DISTINCT (xsd:string(?author_name_) AS ?author_name) { wd:Q5565155 skos:altLabel ?author_name_ . } }
  ?work wdt:P50 wd:Q5565155 .
  ?work wdt:P2093 ?author_name__ .
  FILTER (?author_name = ?author_name__)  
}
```

With the current data in Wikidata, I get five rows returned in this query.

Another way to get this data is by using a `BIND`:

```
SELECT * {
  BIND("Knudsen GM" AS ?author_name)
  ?work wdt:P2093 ?author_name .
}
```

I suppose there might be something wrong with the casting as this does not return anything:

```
SELECT * {
  BIND(xsd:string("Knudsen GM") AS ?author_name)
  ?work wdt:P2093 ?author_name .
}
```

Combinations with `xsd:string` changed to `STR` or no conversion at all in the original query do neither yield result rows.

Comment: it's clearly a bug, you can see the difference in the query execution for the last two queries if you append `&explain` to the URL. The BIND fails for the second query for  some strange reasons. The query without cast shows `with static (exogeneous) bindings defined as follows: 
{
  { author_name=TermId(113382616L)[Knudsen GM] }
}` while the query with cast just has `with static (exogeneous) bindings defined as follows: 
{
  {  }
}`, i.e. is empty in the optimized plan

Comment: @AKSW Should this be an issue reported at https://github.com/blazegraph/database/issues ?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct place. But I'm not sure if there will be a fix for this given that (afaik) Blazegraph technology was bought by Amazon which ships it's own graph database Neptune. From the GitHub project page you can see that latest release (just a release candidate) was Feb. 2017. Nevertheless, reporting issues is always good. Even just to allow others to know this is an issue in the system not their query.

Comment: `SELECT * {
  { SELECT DISTINCT ?author_name { wd:Q5565155 skos:altLabel ?author_name_ . bind (str(?author_name_) AS ?author_name)} }
  hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
  ?work wdt:P2093 ?author_name .
}` BTW, I'm not sure that type casting (e. g. `xsd:string()`) should work for non-primitive types (e.g. for `rdf:langString`) at all.